# Problemas al momento de hacer push con Git

Tags: windows, git, ssh, git-push

gente! Estoy intentando subir mi proyecto en laravel a un vps con una clave SSH a través de PuTTY en Windows. Ya instalé todo en el servidor (LEMP, Composer y Git), sólo me queda hacer un push con git pero me sale este error y no logro entenderlo. Tengo la misma clave SSH en GitHub y en Digital Ocean que es donde tengo el VPS. He buscado por internet pero no he encontrado nada que fuera útil para mi caso, vi varios tutoriales también pero en todos usan alguna distro de Linux o MacOs donde pueden generar SSH sin instalar nada extra. Es la primera vez que intento hacer deploy de en un VPS y agradecería si alguien pudiera guiarme.

```
Warning: Permanently added '104.146.105.54' (ECDSA) to the list of known 
hosts.
root@104.146.105.54: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Gracias de antemano.

****EDIT: Adjunto una imagen.
[image: Captura del error que me tira el bash de GitHub]

Comment: Estás haciendo un push con el protocolo SSH. Dices que lo estás haciendo a traves de putty. ¿Puedes ser más específico? ¿Dónde se está ejecutando el comando que produce el error que has mostrado? (dicho de otra forma, de qué ventana has capturado ese error?)

Comment: si esas descargando un repo con ssh agregastes la llave que generastes en tu maquina al repositorio?

Comment: Hola, Abulafia! Me conectaba al servidor a través de la línea de comandos de PuTTY pero como no me tomaba comandos de git tuve que hacer add remote desde el bash de github en Windows. No tuve problemas para añadirlo pero cuando hice push me apareció el error mencionado.

Comment: Hola, JackNavaRow! He agregado la llave a mí cuenta de github a través de settings, debía hacer algo más?

Comment: @ReyBlanco Cuando usas git bash, las claves públicas/privadas que utilizará no son las que hayas creado con Putty, sino las que tengas en la carpeta `.ssh/` de tu "home".  Tienes las herramientas típicas de unix (`ssh-keygen` y similares) para crear claves nuevas.

Comment: Gracias, Abulafia. Era eso. <3